# WorkManager does not initialize on demand

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I read these instructions: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand
Now I have a MyApplication class, but I can’t understand how to use it and I can’t find clear instruction anywhere

When requesting WorkManager.getInstance, an error is naturally generated because the MyApplication class is not used anywhere. I could not understand how to activate this class for WorkManager.

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
  tools:node="remove"
  android:exported="false" />
```

`MyApplication.java:`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements Configuration.Provider {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return new Configuration.Builder().
        setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)).build();
    }
}
```

I need to solve this problem exactly, so I will be grateful for the good help. How to make on-demand initialization work?

Comment: You need to replace `{applicationId}` with your application id.

Comment: @Gaurav Mall, But at a Google lecture they told me that this variable should itself be substituted

Comment: The Google documentation placed `{` and `}` around it. Something that is within curly brackets is called a wildcard. It needs to be replaced by you.

Comment: @Gaurav Mall, Clear. but still it’s not clear what to do next and I don’t have time to figure it out for a long time

Answer (score 5):

**WorkManager v2.1** introduced on-demand initialization. This means that you don't need to call `WorkManager.initialize()` when you have a custom configuration, calling `getInstance(Context)` is enough.

What is not enough is to call the, now deprecated, `getInstance()` (without the `Context` argument). This is stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand) you linked to.

I also covered it at droidcon Berlin 2019 in my talk "*Embracing WorkManager*". You can find the slides [here](https://speakerdeck.com/nibble/embrace-workmanager?slide=85) and the video recording [here](https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=352671730).

Comment: But for example, if you call this method in onCreate: WorkManager w = WorkManager.getInstance (getApplicationContext ()), then an error will be triggered. he writes that the WorkManager is not initialized

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using WorkManager v2.1 or newer, older WorkManager versions do not include on-demand initialization.
Can you post the logs with the error?

Comment: I am using version 2.2.0.

Comment: Here is the code in onCreate: WorkManager.initialize(this, new Configuration.Builder()
    .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
    .build());

Comment: As I wrote, you don't need to call the initialize method. The `initialize()` method is automatically called the first time that you cal `getInstance(Context)`. This is the whole idea of the "on-demand" initialization.